# latex change heading text

Tags: latex

I want to change the text for certain headings in sections of my latex document.

Specifically, I'm using the book document class, and I want to change the 'Chapter #' heading to some custom text...
Once I've done it by tweaking the included files for latex and the book doc class, but I guess there's a better solution... any ideas?

Comment: LaTeX questions should go to the new LaTeX StackExchange: http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use

```
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{MyChapter}
```

Comment: got it! thank you very much...
Appart from that, I also needed \addto\captionsspanish , since I'm using babel...

Comment: My book starts with a toc, a preface and then the first chapter. The preface is unnumbered (`chapter*{Preface}`) but all its pages get 'Contents' as their header instead of 'Preface'. Your instructions did not solve this. Is there a way to do this?